# What is WP_FRAMELEFT theme part used for?

Tags: windows, themes

Does anybody know what the theme parts `WP_FRAMELEFT`, `WP_SMALLFRAMERIGHT` etc are used for? Google doesn't deliver anything useful. I had a look with [Windows XP Theme Explorer](http://www.soft-gems.net/) at them and they look like the caption of dock panels.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I also searched MSDN and got only one result ([Parts and States](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773210(VS.85).aspx)) which isn't exactly verbose about the meaning of the various constants (and announces itself as preliminary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're defined in vsstyle.h as part of the WINDOWPARTS enum, which is also defined as WINDOWSTYLEPARTS. Neither of these seem to be referenced anywhere else in the Platform SDK as far as I can see. I would guess that they're remnants of a feature that was never completed or was partially removed. vsstyle.h describes itself as defining "VisualStyle Style Guide symbols".